# Add custom field for each item of an order in the admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

In WooCommerce, I am looking for a way to add a custom field to each item of an order in the Admin edit order view, So I could add, for example, a serial numbers to the products that the customer has ordered.

I've searched a lot without finding anything related.

Does anyone know how can I make this?

Thanks.

Comment: **This is not possible** as you can have a custom field by Item in the order, so you can have 100 different custom fields if you have 100 different items for that order… You can only have a number of defined custom fields in the backend edit order view for all orders. This can not be Modular depending of the number of items…